# How to Add SSL to Google Cloud Wordpress Launcher Site

Tags: google-app-engine, ssl, https, cloud

Google provide Wordpress Launcher although in [beta](https://console.cloud.google.com/launcher/details/click-to-deploy-images/wordpress). I have try them by adding custom domain via `Google Cloud DNS`, but i still not success in adding custom domain with `SSL` (`https`).

Any Idea ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Wordpress from Google Click to Deploy launches on Google Compute Engine, not Google App Engine, meaning you are getting an entire Debian virtual machine, not just an App Engine instance. The App Engine instructions are not applicable.

Here's the process I used (replace "www.veggie.com" with your domain):

1. Go to [Deployment Manager](https://console.cloud.google.com/dm/deployments/) and select your Wordpress deployment.
2. Under "Get Started with WordPress", click "SSH" to open a Google Cloud Shell console on the Debian virtual machine hosting your site.
3. If you haven't already, generate a CSR using `openssl req -new -newkey rsa:2048 -nodes -keyout www_veggie_com.key -out www_veggie_com.csr`. [More info](https://www.namecheap.com/support/knowledgebase/article.aspx/9852/0/csrgoogle)
4. You will be prompted with some questions. Answer them using letters and numbers only. For example:

   ```
   Country Name (2 letter code) [AU]:US
   State or Province Name (full name) [Some-State]:New Mexico
   Locality Name (eg, city) []:Albuquerque
   Organization Name (eg, company) [Internet Widgits Pty Ltd]:Veggie Inc   # put "NA" if not applicable
   Organizational Unit Name (eg, section) []:NA                            # put "NA" if not applicable
   Common Name (e.g. server FQDN or YOUR name) []:www.veggie.com           # MUST BE the website you are securing. Use *.veggie.com if you purchased a wildcard certificate
   Email Address []:webmaster@veggie.com
   A challenge password []:                # just leave this blank
   An optional company name []:            # leave this blank too
   ```
5. Move the private key to a safe place, e.g. `sudo mv www_veggie_com.key /etc/ssl/ssl.key/`
6. View the CSR (Certificate Signing Request) file using `cat www_veggie_com.csr`. It should look something like this:

   ```
   -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE REQUEST-----
   sdkfjhksdjfhkjsdvbksdjfkhsdkfhskdjfhskjdfhksdjfhkdsjvbnksjksjkjh
   2398dfjk3290fdsjk3290slk093koldfj3j0igr0/4387yvdjkn4398fdh92439h
   sdkfjhksdjfhkjsdvbksdjfkhsdkfhskdjfhskjdfhksdjfhkdsjvbnksjksjkjh
   2398dfjk3290fdsjk3290slk093koldfj3j0igr0/4387yvdjkn4398fdh92439h
   sdkfjhksdjfhkjsdvbksdjfkhsdkfhskdjfhskjdfhksdjfhkdsjvbnksjksjkjh
   2398dfjk3290fdsjk3290slk093koldfj3j0igr0/4387yvdjkn4398fdh92439h
   sdkfjhksdjfhkjsdvbksdjfkhsdkfhskdjfhskjdfhksdjfhkdsjvbnksjksjkjh
   2398dfjk3290fdsjk3290slk093koldfj3j0igr0/4387yvdjkn4398fdh92439h
   sdkfjhksdjfhkjsdvbksdjfkhsdkfhskdjfhskjdfhksdjfhkdsjvbnksjksjkjh
   2398dfjk3290fdsjk3290slk093koldfj3j0igr0/4387yvdjkn4398fdh92439h
   sdkfjhksdjfhkjsdvbksdjfkhsdkfhskdjfhskjdfhksdjfhkdsjvbnksjksjkjh
   2398dfjk3290fdsjk3290slk093koldfj3j0igr0/4387yvdjkn4398fdh92439h
   sdkfjhksdjfhkjsdvbksdjfkhsdkfhskdjfhskjdfhksdjfhkdsjvbnksjksjkjh
   sdkfjhksdjfhkjsdvbksdjfkhsdkfhskdjfhskjdfhksdjfhkdsjvbnksjksjkjh
   2398dfjk3290fdsjk3290slk093koldfj3j0igr0/4387yvdjkn4398fdh92439h
   3fjkbdjgkedkj4vie929ckw0gfjdfgjs90q=
   -----END CERTIFICATE REQUEST-----
   ```
7. Copy the contents of the CSR file to your clipboard (in Google Cloud Shell, just highlight the text with your mouse and hit Ctrl+C).
8. Go to the site where you purchased the certificate and find the option to *Activate* the certificate. You should be prompted to upload or copy and paste the CSR. If you are prompted to confirm the server type, it is an Apache server. After I did that, my certificate issuer sent me the certificates via email.
9. Once you have your certificates, return to the Google Cloud Shell.
10. Use the gear menu > Upload File to upload your SSL certificates to your server. I put the certificates in `/etc/ssl/ssl.crt/`.
11. Enter `sudo nano /etc/apache2/sites-available/wordpress.conf` to use [Nano](https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/42980/the-beginners-guide-to-nano-the-linux-command-line-text-editor/) to edit your server's configuration file to point to your certificate(s) and your key file. My `wordpress.conf` only had a `<VirtualHost *:80>` section, so I added a `<VirtualHost *:443>` section at the bottom:

    ```
    <VirtualHost *:443>
      ServerAdmin webmaster@veggie.com
      ServerName www.veggie.com:443
      DocumentRoot /var/www/html

      # Copy <Directory /> and other settings from <VirtualHost *:80> here as well

      SSLEngine on
      SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/ssl.crt/www_veggie_com.crt
      SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/ssl.key/www_veggie_com.key
      SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/ssl/ssl.crt/www_veggie_com.ca-bundle
    </VirtualHost>
    ```

    [image: Copy the stuff already in <VirtualHost *:80> and add the SSL lines]
12. Restart the Apache server using `sudo service apache2 restart`
13. Try visiting your homepage via https (e.g. https://www.veggie.com) and see if it worked.

Comment: This is a valid way to add an SSL certificate, but there is an equally valid way here as well that uses Google's stack instead of purchasing a certificate somewhere else. Both method works, but it might be good to disclose that there are at least two ways to get an SSL added to a Wordpress site hosted on Google Cloud Compute.

Answer (score 3):

This is bit of a complicated process. Despite Googles efforts to https the whole internet and the fact that every App Engine app gets a secure appspot.com-subdomain, adding your own domain with your own certificate is bit complicated.

The process is documented [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/console/using-custom-domains-and-ssl)

Comment: not that complicated if you have computer backgrounds

Comment: I think this question has two good answers. It might be helpful to know that this route is using all Google stack and the other answer from @browly is using "industry standard" methods that require purchasing a certificate from an authoritative vendor. Both are valid ways of solving the issue, but I think some disclosure about the two methods would help people new to SSL certificates.

Answer (score 2):

**1. SSH into the server**

SSH into the server running your HTTP website as a user with sudo privileges.

**2. Install snapd**

You'll need to install snapd and make sure you follow any instructions to enable classic snap support.
Follow these instructions on snapcraft's site to install snapd.
https://snapcraft.io/docs/installing-snap-on-debian

**3. Ensure that your version of snapd is up to date**

Execute the following instructions on the command line on the machine to ensure that you have the latest version of snapd.

```
sudo snap install core; sudo snap refresh core
```

**4. Remove certbot-auto and any Certbot OS packages**

If you have any Certbot packages installed using an OS package manager like apt, dnf, or yum, you should remove them before installing the Certbot snap to ensure that when you run the command certbot the snap is used rather than the installation from your OS package manager. The exact command to do this depends on your OS, but common examples are sudo apt-get remove certbot, sudo dnf remove certbot, or sudo yum remove certbot.

If you previously used Certbot through the certbot-auto script, you should also remove its installation by following the instructions here.

**5. Install Certbot**

Run this command on the command line on the machine to install Certbot.

```
sudo snap install --classic certbot
```

**6. Prepare the Certbot command**

Execute the following instruction on the command line on the machine to ensure that the certbot command can be run.

```
sudo ln -s /snap/bin/certbot /usr/bin/certbot
```

**7. Choose how you'd like to run Certbot**

Either get and install your certificates...
Run this command to get a certificate and have Certbot edit your Apache configuration automatically to serve it, turning on HTTPS access in a single step.

```
sudo certbot --apache
```

Or, just get a certificate
If you're feeling more conservative and would like to make the changes to your Apache configuration by hand, run this command.

```
sudo certbot certonly --apache
```

**8. Test automatic renewal**

The Certbot packages on your system come with a cron job or systemd timer that will renew your certificates automatically before they expire. You will not need to run Certbot again, unless you change your configuration.

You can test automatic renewal for your certificates by running this command:

```
sudo certbot renew --dry-run
```

If that command completes without errors, your certificates will renew automatically in the background.

**9. Confirm that Certbot worked**

To confirm that your site is set up properly, visit https://yourwebsite.com/ in your browser and look for the lock icon in the URL bar.

**Source:**
https://certbot.eff.org/lets-encrypt/debianstretch-apache

Answer (score 1):

Here's the steps I used for free SSL certificate on wordpress VM launched in google cloud.

Make sure "Allow http" and "Allow https" are selected in vm settings and also overall firewall rules for the your project has 443/80 rules (which are there by default).

Enabling Free SSL Certificate : 
Change the domain name below from my-domain.com to required domain name.

Step 1 : 
wget https://dl.eff.org/certbot-auto && chmod a+x certbot-auto

sudo ./certbot-auto certonly --webroot -w /var/www/html/ -d my-domain.com -d www.my-domain.com

Step 2:
sudo vi /etc/apache2/sites-available/default-ssl.conf

> Add following  after ServerAdmin

```
<Directory /var/www/html/>
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
AllowOverride All
Order allow,deny
allow from all
</Directory>
```

> At the end of file
>   Comment out two SnakeOil Certs lines and add below.

```
SSLCertificateFile "/etc/letsencrypt/live/my-domain.com/cert.pem"
SSLCertificateKeyFile "/etc/letsencrypt/live/my-domain.com/privkey.pem"
SSLCertificateChainFile "/etc/letsencrypt/live/my-domain.com/chain.pem"
```

Step 3 : 
sudo vi /etc/apache2/sites-available/wordpress.conf

> Remove all 3 lines
>   Add below lines

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html

    ServerName www.my-domain.com
    ServerAlias my-domain.com
    Redirect permanent / https://www.my-domain.com/

    <Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    </Directory>
    <Directory /var/www/html/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
    </Directory>
    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
    <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
    AllowOverride None
    Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
    </Directory>
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
    # alert, emerg.
    LogLevel warn
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Step 4 :

> > Restart apache

```
sudo a2ensite default-ssl
sudo a2enmod ssl
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Step 5 (Optional) :

> > Enable auto renewal for cert :

```
sudo mv certbot-auto /etc/letsencrypt/
sudo crontab -e
```

> > Add following at the end
> >         45 2 * * 6 cd /etc/letsencrypt/ && ./certbot-auto renew && /etc/init.d/apache2 restart

Step 6 : 
Test https version is working in browser.
Only after making sure that https is working : 
Go to WP-Admin : 
Settings > General > change site url and host url to https://my-domain.com

Note : Any error in typing wrong url in step 6, you can loose web access to wordpress. After that, you have to follow other steps to gain the access back through ssh.
Hope this helps.