# Wordpress in Google Cloud "not secure" in browser and not sending emails

Tags: wordpress, email, ssl, google-cloud-platform

I have just installed Wordpress in Google Cloud and I have the "not secure" message in browser bar url.

Besides, just after installation, I have tried to change temporary password, but I can't, as it says Wordpress can't send emails.

I have put ticks in firewall rules to permit HTTP and HTTPS, but I have the "not secure" message in browser when trying to connect to Wordpress admin, for example.

I have tried to change temporary password, clicking on "forgot password" link, but I am not able, as it says "Wordpress can't send emails".

What could or must I do? I am a bit lost.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to add an SSL certificate to your Google Cloud hosted WordPress website. Here are [several ways](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41819613/how-to-add-ssl-to-google-cloud-wordpress-launcher-site) how to do it.

As for your password, you can't change it because, you need to [set up an email service provider](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/tutorials/sending-mail/#choosing_an_email_service_to_use) for Wordpress.